# pymc.NormApprox unexpected behavior - unable to see mu and C and nuking of namespace

Tags: python, pymc

I am new to pymc and enjoying it but have run into some very strange behavior.  I want to use it to track something moving; following the tutorials I set up some stochastics and attempted to use `pymc.NormApprox()` on it. `fit()` seems to run but when I try to get the output out it gives me `KeyError`.  When I switch to using `pymc.MCMC` it runs `sample() OK but then nukes the namespace (Python even forgets how to exit()).

System:  Ubuntu 12.04, scipy numpy etc installed, pymc installed via easy_install; also tried from git.

Code to reproduce: 
test.py::

```
import pymc
import numpy as np

x = pymc.MvNormal('x',mu=np.zeros(4),tau=np.eye(4))

@pymc.deterministic()
def y(x=x):
  out = np.zeros(2)
  out[0] = x[0]+x[2]
  out[1] = x[1]+x[3]
  return out

ymeas = pymc.MvNormal('ymeas',mu=y,tau=np.eye(2)*100000,value=20*np.ones(2),observed=True)
```

Then, in a shell running python or ipython::

```
import test
import pymc
foo = pymc.NormApprox(test)
foo.fit()
foo.mu[foo.x] # Fails - gives KeyError

foo._mu # I can see it OK if I break privacy rules

foo = pymc.MCMC(test)
foo.sample(10000) # runs OK
foo # fails - namespace is nuked
```

What I expect to see:
`foo.mu[foo.x]` should give me the normal approx to the posterior; I shouldn't get a Key error and shouldn't have to break into `foo._mu`

instead I get:

```
>>> foo.mu[foo.x]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymc-2.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pymc/NormalApproximation.py", line 56, in __getitem__
    tot_len += self.owner.stochastic_len[p]
KeyError: 9.9999517411499177
>>> foo._mu
array([  9.99995174,   9.99997163,  10.0000485 ,  10.00002837])
>>>
```

Also I noticed that the docstring for `foo.mu` says `N.mu(p1,p2)` but the online documentation says `N.mu[N.p1,N.p2]`.

As for the post- MCMC namespace meltdown, it even forgets how to exit()

Also I can confirm that I get the same problem on a different machine (MacBook Pro) running a different installation (Enthought Python).